# How to see all the flags that have been applied between -O1 to O2 optimization level in clang compiler

Tags: clang

I am working with individual optimization flags have been applied in different level of optimization with clang compiler . I tried a lot but did not get any positive site .

How to get list of optimization flags in O1 , O2 , O3 level . The way we get from gcc using command
gcc -c -Q -O3 --help=optimizers

I looked clang documentation but did not get anything

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following commands to look at different passes that execute with specified the optimization level:

clang -O3 -mllvm -debug-pass=Arguments out.bc -disable-output

opt -O3 -debug-pass=Arguments out.bc -disable-output

Comment: This command is not working . Its showing "clang-15: error: no such file or directory: 'out.bc'
clang-15: error: no input files"

Comment: How can I get the list of O3 level optimization flags for clang/LLVM

Comment: You can use a small program and convert it to out.bc. The above command requires an input file.

Comment: I am working with benchmark . So this will work on multiple files . I just want to know what are the optimization flags have been applied for each level . How to see that without any input file . We can see in GCC but I could not find any effective command in llvm

Comment: The above mentioned command is used to print the list of passes that are executed with the specified optimization level for the given input file. However, some input file in .bc format needs to be specified. You can use any small program for this purpose. The list of passes will remain the same irrespective of the input file, as it depends on the optimization level.